# Usage of !false in a do-while loop

Tags: javascript

I saw a do-while loop that looked something like

```
var guess = false;
do {
    stuff stuff stufff
    if ( things ===  things){
        guess = true;
    }
} while ( ! guess )
```

This confused me because the ! operator changes the boolean value to the opposite, so that guess becomes true instead of false. So "while not false" the do-while keeps running? Or does this mean "while true" it keeps running or...?

thanks for the help!

Comment: [do..while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) condition:
An expression evaluated after each pass through the loop. If condition evaluates to true, the statement is re-executed. When condition evaluates to false, control passes to the statement following the do...while.

Comment: Apparently you think `!guess` changes the value of `guess`? Because it does not, it simply evaluates to the logical negation, just like `a + b` does not change the value of a or b, it simply evaluates to the sum.

Comment: *! operator changes the boolean value to the opposite?* No, it returns the INVERSE of the value. It does **not** change the value.

Comment: got it! thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while(!guess)` means *"while guess is not true"*.

It also can be written as `while(guess == false)`. Maybe that way is easier to understand, although it is not a good practice.

There are some examples here: [MDN - Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!))

Comment: ahh this explains it. thank you very much for clearing that up for me

Answer (score -1):

the actual format would be

```
if (things == things)
{
   coding here......
}
```

the `==` mean is equal to.
the `>=` means greater than or equal too.
the `<=` means less than or equal to.
the `!=` means that its not equal to.

so if you change the operators this would be

`if (things == things)` which means things are equal to things. 
`if (things >= things)` which means things is greater than or equal to the things.

Follow the steps and for example when you use this in speech it would look like

```
if (speech == "things")
{
   do coding.........
}
```

the speech is equal to things then the code will be executed

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. And I'm no JS expert, but I think the operator === is the actual correct implementation (tests for value and type equality).

Comment: `==` is a comparison operator. `===` operator also compares operands types. The code provided by OP is valid while this answer does not provides any information about an actual question.